# R Create multiple columns based on two different parameters

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, which has 2 columns: date and return. Now I want to mutate multiple new columns, that are depending on two parameters: the threshold-parameter and the lag-parameter. The functionality is simple. The new column is calculated as follows:

```
var= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day)>threshold,return, NA))
```

If the `lag(return)` is higer than the threshold, than give me the `return`-value, else give me `NA`.

Here are the values for the thresholds and the lag_days:

```
threshold=c(2,4,6)
lag_day=c(1,2,3)
```

Here I'm solving my problem manually:

```
test<-df%>%
  mutate(var_t1_lag1= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[1] )>threshold[1],return, NA))%>%
  mutate(var_t2_lag1= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[1] )>threshold[2],return, NA))%>%
  mutate(var_t3_lag1= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[1] )>threshold[3],return, NA))%>%
  mutate(var_t1_lag2= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[2] )>threshold[1],return, NA))%>%
  mutate(var_t2_lag2= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[2] )>threshold[2],return, NA))%>%
  mutate(var_t3_lag2= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[2] )>threshold[3],return, NA))%>%
  mutate(var_t1_lag3= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[3] )>threshold[1],return, NA))%>%
  mutate(var_t2_lag3= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[3] )>threshold[2],return, NA))%>%
  mutate(var_t3_lag3= ifelse(lag(return, n= lag_day[3] )>threshold[3],return, NA))
```

But is there a solution that would it make easier? Maybe with one or two apply-functions?

Here is my example-dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(
  date= today()+0:12,
  return=c(1,2.5,2,3,5,6.5,1,9,3,2,4,7,2)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to get all the combinations of 'threshold', 'lag_day' with `crossing`, then loop through the rows (`pmap`), `transmute` to create the columns of interest and bind with the original dataset. This uses one function from `base R` (`seq_along`)

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(threshold = seq_along(threshold), lag_day) %>%
    pmap_dfc(~  
             df %>%
               transmute(!! str_c("var_t", ..1, "_lag", ..2) := 
                  case_when(lag(return, n = ..2) > threshold[..1] ~ return, 
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_))) %>% 
   bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: It's better to omit `threshold[ ]` in the 5th line of the function. Otherwise it can lead to errors. Now I'm working with the changed function: `case_when(lag(return, n = ..2) > ..1 ~ return, `  (only line 5 is changed)

Comment: @TobKel  Initialy, I was using `crossing(threshold, lag_day)` and with `..1`, but then I need to change the column names based on the sequence, that is the reason I used `seq_along` with `threshold[..1]`.  Interestingly, it is not giving an error for me

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach using two apply loops with `dplyr::lag`

```
df[paste0("var_t", outer(seq_along(lag_day), seq_along(threshold),
   FUN = paste, sep = "_"))] <-  do.call(cbind, 
     lapply(lag_day, function(x) sapply(threshold, function(y) 
            ifelse(dplyr::lag(df$return, n = x) > y, df$return, NA))))


#   date       return var_t1_1 var_t2_1 var_t3_1 var_t1_2 var_t2_2 var_t3_2 var_t1_3 var_t2_3 var_t3_3
#   <date>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 2019-05-21    1       NA       NA         NA     NA         NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2 2019-05-22    2.5     NA       NA         NA     NA         NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 3 2019-05-23    2        2       NA         NA     NA         NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 4 2019-05-24    3       NA       NA         NA      3         NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 5 2019-05-25    5        5       NA         NA     NA         NA       NA        5       NA       NA
# 6 2019-05-26    6.5      6.5      6.5       NA      6.5       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 7 2019-05-27    1        1        1          1      1          1       NA        1       NA       NA
# 8 2019-05-28    9       NA       NA         NA      9          9        9        9        9       NA
# 9 2019-05-29    3        3        3          3     NA         NA       NA        3        3        3
#10 2019-05-30    2        2       NA         NA      2          2        2       NA       NA       NA
#11 2019-05-31    4       NA       NA         NA      4         NA       NA        4        4        4
#12 2019-06-01    7        7       NA         NA     NA         NA       NA        7       NA       NA
#13 2019-06-02    2        2        2          2      2         NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```